# Converting time from UTC to Local and vice versa

Tags: windows, visual-c++, time, timezone

I am trying to figure out a way to convert a `FILETIME` structure from UTC to Local and vice versa.

I've been using the two functions: `FileTimetoLocalFileTime()` and `LocalFileTimeToFileTime()`. The problem seems that they do not work as expected.

As an example: First I got a local file time using:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
FindFirstFile(_T("Path:To:File"), &fd);
```

now fd has the last write date in local format.

Then I use `LocalFileTimeToFileTime()` to convert the last write date to UTC and then convert that FILETIME structure to an 64bit integer as described in MSDN. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188768
Then I store that number in a DB for later.

Now when I change the timezone for example, I get the 64bit integer from the DB. Convert it into a `FILETIME` structure and then try to convert it to its local value. Using `FileTimeToLocalFileTime()`. The problem is that when I compare that file time with the local time of the same file and of course making sure that no changes have been made to the file. The times are different. I am not sure why but its like that every time.

I Would also like to know if there is a possible way to convert the `FILETIME` as is to a readable string. Without using `CTime or SYSTEMTIME` since both of them convert the `FILETIME` to its UTC equivalent which I don't really want, as I would like to see the exact converted time from both functions `LocalFileTimeToFileTime() and FileTimeToLocalFileTime().`

Hope I've explained the situation, and hope someone would help me achieve my goal

Comment: FILETIME is already UTC (for NTFS).

Comment: Not really, for example the FILETIME extracted from the WIN32_FIND_DATA is always different when you change the timezone. If it was in UTC then it should be always the same no matter what. Unless Microsoft is playing games with us.

Comment: What OS are you using?  I'm using Windows XP SP3 and changing the time zone has no effect on the FILETIMEs in the WIN32_FIND_DATA struct.

Comment: I just tested with Windows 7 and the FILETIME is always the same UTC value.  Is the file on a FAT32 drive?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. The machine that I was testing on was out of my reach when I posted my last comment. and the drive was formatted in FAT32. on NTFS the values are always the same.

Well, til I figure this out. Im still looking for an answer to my second question on how to convert the FILETIME to a readable string without messing with it. its probably a simple mathematical operation but its flying over my mind now.

Comment: Converting a FILETIME to a time_t is straightforward enough; from there you could do whatever you need.